# Adding graphable note to org-mode clock

Tags: org-mode

In addition to monitoring how much time I spend on a task, I'd also like to note what's going on in that time block. It'd be useful to have it appear in the clocktable, or some other means so that I can graph this column against the time. Is this in any way possible?

edit: for example, I want to rate each time block, on scale 1 to 10, how much work actually gets done, and I want to be able to graph this quality vs time.

Comment: Seems interesting but I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "what's going on in that time block" and "graph this column against the time"?

Comment: An example is: I want to rate each time block, on scale 1 to 10, how much work actually gets done. I'm interested in seeing how time correlates to quality, basically, and because org-mode's clocktable is already so convenient I'd like to be able to build on that.

Comment: You could tag each item with something like "q1" to "q10" and then get ten separate clock tables for each rating, like so: `#+BEGIN: clocktable :tags "+q1"`. But I can't find any existing functionality that will get you any further then that.

Comment: It looks like the idea of adding a column for tags right in the clock table has been discussed, but I'm not sure anything ever came of it: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2011-05/msg00219.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to use existing features instead of coding your own elisp function, you might have better luck with column view then clock reports. Here is an example of an org-mode file:

```
* Work
 :PROPERTIES:
 :COLUMNS: %50ITEM %Quality %CLOCKSUM
 :END:
 ** A long day of hard work
 :PROPERTIES:
 :Quality:  10
 :END:
    CLOCK: [2015-03-24 Tue 07:20]--[2015-03-24 Tue 21:20] => 14:00
 ** A few minutes of messing around
 :PROPERTIES:
 :Quality:  1
 :END:                   
    CLOCK: [2015-03-25 Wed 11:10]--[2015-03-25 Wed 11:20] =>  0:10
```

You can sort by `Quality` (<kbd>C-c ^</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd>) first, then enter column view with  <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd>. <kbd>Tab</kbd> to fold and you can get a result like this.

[image]

And finally, if you want to extend this further and literally "graph" your work, that should be possible by adding [a `columnview` dynamic block](http://orgmode.org/manual/Capturing-column-view.html).